# How many bridge hands have exactly two 5-cards suits and a void so that the remaining suit has a run of 3 cards?

Tags: combinations

> How many bridge hands have exactly two 5-cards suits and a void so that the remaining suit has a run of 3 cards?

Should the answer be $C(13,5)C(13,5)C(4,2)C(13,3)$.I first choose $5$ cards for each of the $5$-card suits,then choosing $2$ suits from $4$ suits for the two $5$-card suits.Since there's a void in the bridge hands,the remaining cards are of the same suit.I just need to choose the remaining $3$ cards from $52-13-13-13=13$ cards.

Comment: also you need to pick which of the two remaining suits has the void, so multiply by C(2,1)=2

Comment: But like the question here:How many bridge hands have a 5-card suit that must contain the ace of that suit, a 4-card suit, and a void (no cards of a suit)?   The answer is :C(12,4)C(4,1)C(13,4)C(3,1)C(13,4)   I don't need to pick up which of the two remaining suits has the void.Why's that?

Comment: I think you do need to pick up which of the remaining suits in that case also

Comment: I take it that a run of $3$ cards here just means any three cards, like you have taken in your attempt

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion evident in comments, I follow this practice

- write the # of cards distributed to the hands in descending order
- permute the hands
- distribute cards to the hands

For your problem the pattern is $5-5-3-0$ with $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}$ permutations,
so the answer is $\dfrac{4!}{2!1!1!}C(13,5)C(13,5)C(13,3)$

And for the problem in your comments,
the pattern is $5-4-4-0$, with $\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}= 12$ permutations,
and with the ace condition attached,
the distribution is $C(12,4)C(13,4)C(13,4)$

so clearly $C(4,1)C(3,1)=12$ shouldn't be multiplied by $C(2,1)$